# popup model is not closing react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created one component. in which I have a button in which once you click popup will be displayed. data for that popup is put in another component. below is the popup.

```
function Places() {
  const [showModel, setShowModel] = useState(null)

  const handleToggleModel = (value) => {
    setShowModel(value)
  }

  return (
  <div className='hotel-container'>
        <div
          className='hotel-container_groupA'
          onClick={() => handleToggleModel(auli)}
        >
          <Article imgUrl={auli} date='Sep 26, 2021' text='Aoli' />
          {showModel === auli && (
            <Model onClose={() => handleToggleModel(null)}>
              <div>
                <img src={auli} alt='#' />
              </div>
            </Model>
          )}
        </div>
)
```

now on the close button component

```
const Model = ({ children, onClose }) => {


  return (
    <div className='model'>
      <div className='model-content'>
        {children}
        <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is your onClick for setting the **showModel** state to *auli* coinciding with close button on your popup. You should move the Model component out of div.

```
export function Places() {
  const [showModel, setShowModel] = useState(null)
  const handleToggleModel = (value) => {
    setShowModel(value)
  }

  return (
  <div className='hotel-container'>
    <div
      className='hotel-container_groupA'
      onClick={() => handleToggleModel(auli)}
    >
    <Article imgUrl={auli} date='Sep 26, 2021' text='Aoli' />  
    </div>
    {showModel === auli && (
      <Model onClose={() => handleToggleModel(null)}>
        <div>
          <img src={auli} alt='#' />
        </div>
      </Model>
    )}
  </div>
)}
```